# Removing a controller name from a URL in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm dynamically constructing URLs to pass to a jQuery button click event handler.

The URL comes from a modal window definition:

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="modal-view-tenant-profile" 
data-url="Tenants/ViewProfile">...</div>
```

The id comes from a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block show-modal" 
data-id="@result.UserId">View profile</button>
```

In my JS function I grab both pieces of data

```
var url = "Tenants/ViewProfile";
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

and construct the URL like this `$.get(url + '/' + id, function (data))...`

To work, the URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost:1840/Tenants/ViewProfile/2
```

but because this controller action is invoked from a logged in Lanlord the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:1840/Landlords/Tenants/ViewProfile/2
```

I understand that I need to create a new route to ignore the 'Landlord' part of the URL, how do I do this when a landlord is invoking an action from the tenant contoller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add backslash before Tenants

```
var url = "/Tenants/ViewProfile";
```

Comment: I actually tried something similar but didn't include the backslash before  Tenants. It works, thanks.